How can I use duckdb from commandline?
I got the windows duckdb and installed it from https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/index?version=stable&environment=cli&platform=win&download_method=package_manager
I typed in the following
c:\duckdb_cli-windows-amd64>duckdb
v1.0.0 1f98600c2c
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
D SELECT * from "H:\SoftwareQA\Test\TestFramework1\resources\models.csv"

Then i get this ┬╖ on the terminal...How do i proceed? What is this ┬╖??
Shown below.
c:\duckdb_cli-windows-amd64>duckdb
v1.0.0 1f98600c2c
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
D SELECT * from "H:\\SoftwareQA\\Test\\TestFramework1\\resources\\models.csv"
┬╖ select *
┬╖ view
┬╖ .help
┬╖

I was expecting the terminal to not suddenly change. Where can i find more information on this?

I originally thought this was a font / encoding issue, but I can replicate it. I was able to get duckdb to output the query, but only after executing the command:
select * from read_csv("path_to_file.csv")
Then, when getting the ┬╖, terminating the command.
╰─ # duckdb
v1.0.0 1f98600c2c
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
D SELECT * FROM read_csv("C:\Users\Dustin\Downloads\username.csv")
┬╖
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ Username  │ Identifier │ First name │ Last name │
│  varchar  │   int64    │  varchar   │  varchar  │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼───────────┤
│ booker12  │       9012 │ Rachel     │ Booker    │
│ grey07    │       2070 │ Laura      │ Grey      │
│ johnson81 │       4081 │ Craig      │ Johnson   │
│ jenkins46 │       9346 │ Mary       │ Jenkins   │
│ smith79   │       5079 │ Jamie      │ Smith     │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────────┘

EDIT: After fussing with it in WSL, I was able to get proper output without the weird character, and I noticed that the issue was with the query formatting:
select * from read_csv("path_to_csv.csv");
The semi-colon is absolutely required at the end, to specify the query is over. Otherwise, its looking for a Unicode character that for some reason, doesn't appear in the windows terminal, even with various fonts.


What is this ┬╖??

It’s evidently the result of an attempt to render the DuckDB prompt, which is normally a D followed by a space.  You kept on seeing it because you were not understanding the hint that a semicolon is needed to terminate an SQL command. It’s not needed to terminate a “dot” command.
